# How to verify a file automatically over sftp?

Tags: sftp, verification

I am trying to create a cron job to perform backup of a server over the internet using sftp. But before the actual backup is performed, I would like to verify that the server is connecting to the correct backup machine as its IP address may change periodically.

My idea is to put a file containing a checksum say `abc123` in the sftp folder of the backup machine and let the server read and compare this checksum first before performing the backup transfer. I have already set up the ssh key to allow authentication without password. How do I go about performing this verification with sftp command?

Comment: I don't think sftp has a way to invoke such a process -- but you can certainly do it with ssh by calling a script or shell function remotely before doing the transfer, e.g. "ssh my-server-name '/bin/bash -c "if [ $(hostname) == my-server-name ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi"'   ... the expression in single quotes will cause ssh to return an error if the hostname command on the backup machine doesn't match your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH already takes care of this. The first time you connect to a server from a client, the client records the public key of the server in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. If the key changes in a subsequent connection, `ssh` will complain that the server is being impersonated and refuse to connect. (This mechanism can be deactivated by configuration option, but… don't do it.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am looking at the wrong way of doing things. Thanks for pointing out the proper way :)